# ExtractZipFile for cordova 2.3.0 android

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I would like to know how you get ExtractZipFile plugin to the latest cordova 2.3. I have tried to get the plugin working but did not win.

link to plugin
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ExtractZipFile

Hope someone can help me.

regards

Comment: I am sure someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified Vishal Rajpal (the author of the ExtractZipFile plugin) code to comply with the cordova plugin structure, as documented in [Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) and [Developing a Plugin on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android).

**Java code** to be put in the src directory under org/apache/cordova/plugin/ExtractZipFilePlugin.java

```
/*
    Author: Vishal Rajpal
    Filename: ExtractZipFilePlugin.java
    Created Date: 21-02-2012
    Modified Date: 21-02-2013
    Modified to comply with Cordova by: Ran Friedlender
*/

package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipException;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class ExtractZipFilePlugin extends CordovaPlugin
{
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException
    {
        if (action.equals("unzip"))
        {
            String filename = args.getString(0); 
            unzip(filename, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void unzip(String filename, CallbackContext callbackContext)
    {
        File file = new File(filename);
        String[] dirToSplit = filename.split(File.separator);
        String dirToInsert = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < dirToSplit.length - 1; i++)
        {
            dirToInsert += dirToSplit[i] + File.separator;
        }

        BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
        BufferedInputStream is = null;
        ZipEntry entry;
        ZipFile zipfile;

        try
        {
            zipfile = new ZipFile(file);
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries();

            while (e.hasMoreElements()) 
            {
                entry = (ZipEntry)e.nextElement();
                is = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry), 8192);
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[102222];
                String fileName = dirToInsert + entry.getName();
                File outFile = new File(fileName);

                if (entry.isDirectory()) 
                {
                    outFile.mkdirs();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                    dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 102222);

                    while ((count = is.read(data, 0, 102222)) != -1)
                    {
                        dest.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    dest.flush();
                    dest.close();
                    is.close();
                  }
            }
        }
        catch (ZipException e1)
        {
            callbackContext.error(PluginResult.Status.MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION.toString());
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            callbackContext.error(PluginResult.Status.IO_EXCEPTION.toString());
            return;
        }

        callbackContext.success(filename);
    }
}
```

**Plugin declaration** to be put in res/xml/config.xml under plugins

```
<plugin name="ZipPlugin" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.ExtractZipFilePlugin" />
```

**JavaScript code** to be included in your project - file ZipPlugin.js

```
/*
    Author: Vishal Rajpal
    Filename: ZipPlugin.js
    Created Date: 21-02-2012
    Modified Date: 21-02-2013
    Modified to comply with Cordova by: Ran Friedlender
*/

var ExtractZipFilePlugin = function()
{
};

ExtractZipFilePlugin.prototype.extractFile = function(file, successCallback, errorCallback) 
{
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "ZipPlugin", "unzip", [file]);
};
```

**Usage example**

```
var ZipClient = new ExtractZipFilePlugin();
ZipClient.extractFile("my_path/my.zip", win, fail);

function win(status) 
{    
    alert('Success ' + status);
}    

function fail(error) 
{ 
    alert(error);
}
```

Tested successfully with cordova 2.4.0

Cheers!

Comment: i had issues in this one but now i cam up . Thanks for showing path

Comment: For reference, Nattawat Nonsung modified it for 3.0.0 http://nattawat-nonsung.blogspot.hk/2013/11/android-plugin-to-extract-zip-file-in.html

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same problem than i modified And this phonegap unzip plugin working fine in 2.6

[Unzip plugin](https://github.com/ashishanautiyal/Unzip-PhoneGap--Plugin)