# Geolocation with PhoneGap on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation, gps

I work on an application that using PhoneGap. For the moment, I only test it on Android. I have several pages in my application that need the geolocation feature.

So I made a JS to handle it with this line of code (of course it's not my unique line of code) :
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(successGeolocation, errorGeolocation, {maximumAge: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});

The geolocation need to be the most accurate possible so I use the GPS and it can take some time to have a GPS Fix.

The problem is when the user navigates from one page to another. The WatchPosition stop (it's normal because the user load an other page) and when I recall it the GPS need to Fix again.

It's very annoying and I search a solution to keep the GPS active. Someone has an idea for me ? Maybe with a plugin or a native Android LoC I can keep it active during all the application life ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've found a possible fix but it's VERY ugly and I don't want to do that... I can make a single page to embeed my JS and then create a DIV for each screen in it. Then I hide all DIV except the one I want to view, but with this solution I have all my HTML code in one single file !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step you should create an Android plugin that will give you API for receiving the location data.

Creating a plugin is quite easy and is explained here:
[Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) and [Developing a Plugin on Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android).
You can also see an example of creating a Cordova plugin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991641/1755778).

Next, create a location monitor class. You can make it singleton and initialize it from your main activity.

Here is a simple, but working code I compiled from several sources and many tests to fit my needs.
The main code is taken from [here](https://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/LocationApp), though I simplified it as much as was possible.

```
public class LocationMonitor
{
    private LocationListener locationListener = null;
    private LocationManager locationManager = null;
    private Location location = null;


    public LocationMonitor()
    {
    }

    public void startGPSActivity(Context context)
    {
        LocationLooper looper = new LocationLooper();
        looper.start();

        while (!looper.isReady())
        {
        }

        looper.handler.post(new LocationBootstrapper(context));
    }

    public void stopGPSActivity()
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    public Location getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    private class LocationLooper extends Thread
    {
        private Handler handler;

        private LocationLooper()
        {
        }

        public void run()
        {
            Looper.prepare();

            this.handler = new Handler();

            Looper.loop();
        }

        public boolean isReady()
        {
            return this.handler != null;
        }
    }


    private class LocationBootstrapper implements Runnable
    {       
        private Context context;

        private LocationBootstrapper(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            locationListener = new LocationListenerImpl();
            locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);
        }
    }


    private class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener
    {
        private LocationListenerImpl()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            LocationMonitor.this.location = location;
            Log.i("LocationMonitor", "New location: lat= " + location.getLatitude() + " lng=" + location.getLongitude() + " acc=" + location.getAccuracy());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
        {       
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
        {       
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
        {       
        }
    }
}
```

Now access the LocationMonitor class from your plugin and you have your desired solution - page changes will not re-initialize your GPS and location data is available to your PhoneGap app.

Cheers